# Why is my swift firestore getDocument query not returning anything?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

new to swift and coding in general, and working with swiftUI exclusively.

After reviewing documentation from the swift SDK, I am trying to implement a basic query to check if a document exists in a collection. I've read answers on similar questions but no direct correlation to my issue as far as I can see.

Here is the documentation I am referring to:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Here is the code:

```
let fullrefplacesIndex = db.collection("users").document(currentUserId!.uid).collection("places").document("placesIndex")
        
        fullrefplacesIndex.getDocument { (document, error) in
            
            print("This line does not get executed")
            
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("places index Document data: \(dataDescription)")
            } else {
                print("places index Document does not exist")
            }
        }
        
        print("This is the first line executed after the getDocument method call.")
```

It is taken verbatim from the documentation, but when I run it, it executes the first line to call the getDocument method, and then nothing else. Doesn't execute the 'if let' Optional binding line or anything below it until after the trailing closure of the method call.

Other information:

- Code is part of a method that is part of a class that is instantiated as an environment object.
- The call is from a button in a view.
- The path reference is correct and works.

Is it because it is running asynchronously? And I need to add a listener? If so, can someone direct me on how to do this so that it will check if the document exists when it receives the call back from the server?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like another topic with the synchronous thing.

Comment: Yeah it was.  I worked it out, thanks for responding.